# Export CVS sub-path of module

Tags: cvs

How can I export a sub-path within a project? I have CVSROOT set as an environment variable, and have already logged in.

This works:

```
cvs export -D now path/to/module
```

This doesn't:

```
cvs export -D now path/to/module/subdir
```

I want to export only "subdir" and not the whole module.

Answer (score 0):

I had been getting the following error, even when run in an empty directory:

```
cvs [export aborted]: cannot export into a working directory
```

There must have been some connection issue between me and the server, because that command is working now, and I don't know why it wasn't before.